# ayuda android msqlserver

Tags: android, base-de-datos, api

Tengo que acceder a una aplicación con el login y la pass correcta, una vez accedo me muestra el nombre en la actividad de consultas del usuario que inicio sesión.

Ahora necesito saber las llamadas no atendidas de dicho usuario, los datos del usuario están en una base de datos de un servidor msql y los datos de las tareas están en otra base de datos del mismo servidor. ¿Cómo puedo sacar las llamadas no atendidas de dicho usuario?

**Actividad 1** esta me permite el acceso a los datos con un usuario en concreto de la bd me funciona correctamente el problema esta en la actividad 2

```
package com.example.usuario.controlllamadas;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static android.R.attr.password;
import static android.R.attr.userVisible;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Connection conn;
    Button btnlogin;
    EditText euser,epass;
    TextView tuser,tpass;
    String CUsuario;
    String Pwd;
    Boolean prueba=false,prueba2=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAceptar);
        euser=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtUsuario);
        epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtPassword);
        tuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Pwd= epass.getText().toString();
                CUsuario=euser.getText().toString();
                Login tarea6=new Login(euser.getText().toString(),epass.getText().toString());
                tarea6.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        public Login(String usuario, String contraseña) {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String...usuario) {
            conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
            try {
                prueba = false;
                prueba2=false;
                String stsql = "SELECT CUsuario,Pwd FROM dbo.xUser WHERE CUsuario='"+CUsuario+"' or Pwd='"+Pwd+"'";
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(stsql);

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        if(CUsuario.equals(rs.getString(1)) && Pwd.equals(rs.getString(2))) {
                            prueba = true;
                            CUsuario = rs.getString(1);
                            Pwd = rs.getString(2);
                        }
                        else if(CUsuario.equals(rs.getString(1))) {
                            prueba2=true;

                         }
                        }
                }catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress(100);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (CUsuario.equals("") || Pwd.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inserta un usuario y una contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
            }

            else if (prueba==true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "acceso permitido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText(CUsuario);
                epass.setText("");
                String userstring = euser.getText().toString();
                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                siguiente.putExtra("USUARIO", userstring);
                startActivity(siguiente);
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
                prueba=false;
            }
            else if ((prueba == false)&&(prueba2==false)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contraseña y usuario incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "usuario correcto,contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                epass.setText("");
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {//este es para interactuar con la interfaz grafica mientras esta en ejecucion la tarea asyncrona
            int progreso = values[0].intValue();
        }

    }

}
```

}

**Actividad 2** esta me indica en un `textview` el usuario con el que inicie sesión ahora lo que necesito son las llamadas no atendidas de ese usuario pero como están en un mismo servidor en dos bases de datos diferentes no se como hacer la consulta.

```
package com.example.usuario.controlllamadas;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
  Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    public TextView t1;
    Connection conn3,conn;
    String[]llamadas;
    int IdLlamada;
    Date Fecha;
    String Mensaje;
    String De;
    String IdUsuarioDestino;
    String Cusuario;
    boolean Estado;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btnllamadasatendidas);
        btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btnllamadasperdidas);
        btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btncerrar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user= intent.getStringExtra("USUARIO");
        t1.setText(user);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               RegistroLlamadasatendidas tareaatendidas=new RegistroLlamadasatendidas();
               tareaatendidas.execute();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           RegistroLlamadasperdidas tareaperdidas=new RegistroLlamadasperdidas();
            tareaperdidas.execute();
        }
});
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cerrar();

            }
        });
    }

    private void cerrar() {
        finish();
    }
```

lo iba a hacer en una tarea asíncrona pasando el campo `textview` que ya me tiene recogido el usuario lo tengo de esta manera ¿alguien me lo puede solucionar?

```
private class RegistroLlamadasperdidas extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
        public RegistroLlamadasperdidas() {
            super();
        }
        String consulta5;
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            conn3 = DBConnection3.getInstance().getConnection();
            try {
              //  String stsql = "Select IdLlamada,Fecha,Mensaje,De,IdUsuarioDestino,Estado from dbo.Llamadas where Estado='0' and CUsuario='"+t1+"' ORDER BY IDLlamada asc";
                //String stsql = "Select IdLlamada,Fecha,Mensaje,De,IdUsuarioDestino,Estado from dbo.Llamadas where Estado='0' ORDER BY IDLlamada asc";
                String stsql = "Select sxPhoenix. dbo.xUser.dbo.CUsuario,IdLlamada,Fecha,Mensaje,De,IdUsuarioDestino,Estado from dbo.Llamadas,dbo.xUser where Estado='0' and CUsuario='"+t1+"' ORDER BY IDLlamada asc";

           //  ""'wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUser.IdLlamada,wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUserdbo.Fecha,wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUserdbo.Mensaje=Mensaje,wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUserdbo.De=De,wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUserdbo.IdUsuarioDestino=IdUsuarioDestino,wordFlow.sxPhoenix.dbo.xUserdbo.Estado=Estado
             //   FROM sxPhoenix.dbo.xUser INNER
                //FROM BASE1.dbo.TABLA1
                //INNER JOIN BASE2.dbo.TABLA2 ON BASE2.dbo.TABLA2.CAMPO2.ID=BASE1.dbo.TABLA1.ID
                Statement st = conn3.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(stsql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    IdLlamada = rs.getInt(1);
                    Fecha = rs.getDate(2);
                    Mensaje = rs.getString(3);
                    De = rs.getString(4);
                    IdUsuarioDestino = rs.getString(5);
                    Estado =true;
                    Cusuario=rs.getString(6);
                    consulta5 = "IdLlamada" + rs.getInt(1) + " Fecha " + rs.getDate(2) + " Mensaje " + rs.getString(3) + " De " + rs.getString(4) + " IdUsuarioDestino " + rs.getString(5)+ " CUsuario " + rs.getString(6);
                    System.out.println("IdLlamada" + rs.getInt(1) + " Fecha " + rs.getDate(2) + " Mensaje " + rs.getString(3) + " De " + rs.getString(4) + " IdUsuarioDestino " + rs.getString(5) + "Estado" + rs.getBoolean("Estado")+ "CUsuario" + rs.getString(6));
                }

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(100);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {

            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if (Estado=true) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "registro de llamadas perdidas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
             Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,consulta5,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}
        }
```

Comment: Hola! agrega tu codigo de lo que tienes hecho, para ver el contexto en el que estas trabajando. Y lo que necesitas de forma clara

Comment: voy ahora te lo copio

Comment: @sstan me confundí y entendí que era MySql, fallo mio, lo siento mucho